# Ignore tmp folder in Subversion

Tags: svn

Whenever I create a new Ruby on Rails project, I tell SVN to ignore some folders, such as log. It's simple to do, with these commands:

```
svn remove log/*
svn propset svn:ignore "*" log/
```

Another folder which shoud obviously not make it to SVN is tmp. So, I always try to do the same operations on it but SVN doesn't seem to ignore it... It sends me those messages in order when I execute the previous commands:

```
svn: 'tmp' is not a working copy
svn: warning: 'tmp' is not under version control
```

Seems fine to me... the problem is that the "svn status" commands still output this:

```
?       tmp
```

How can I get rid of this question mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `tmp` directory name to the svn:ignore property for the *parent directory*:

```
svn propset svn:ignore tmp .
```

Note that the `svn:ignore` property is a multiline list of file patterns to ignore, so it's usually better to edit it with [`svn propedit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propedit.html):

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Using `svn propset` will completely overwrite whatever else you had in that property when setting the new value.

Comment: You are my hero, Greg! Thanks a lot!